# Pattern filling uneditable

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've created some pattern in CS6 (object->pattern->make) and filled with that pattern some square.
I've deleted the source elements from the file but I still can edit the elements is pattern edition mode.

I cannot edit the elements inside the square filled with that pattern and because of that the stock site has rejected the whole work.

How can I make the pattern filling to be editable (when I fill the square with the pattern I cannot change elements inside this square), where is the fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back-saving Illustrator files to older versions and to the EPS format can often cause the flattening and rasterizing of objects based upon appearance settings.

The best, and basically, only advice I can offer is to ensure your artwork is flat (no transparency or effects) prior to saving as an EPS. Even more so for an older EPS format.

It is difficult to provide any further feedback without knowing exact construction of the pattern itself.

Comment: Actually, now I am asking about native CS6 format - I opened the CS6 source file and cannot edit the filling there too. No connection to conversion in this question (I've reasked because realized that the problem is not related to conversion).

Comment: Then the problem is something else. There's no feasible way to answer without a sample file. Editable patterns do not suddenly become uneditable if you save to the same version you are working in.

Comment: pattern itself is editable, but the filling performed with it gives the elements that cannot be edited...

Comment: I fill that it is regular behavior - I cannot edit the elements in the square filled with the parent patterns of Illustrator, so I don't know where is the problem %(

Comment: The **point** of a pattern fill is that you don't *want* to edit the pattern when it is applied to an object. No pattern fills are directly editable when applied to an object. That's how Illustrator works. If you want to edit a pattern after it is applied you need to use the `Expand` items in the `Object` Menu, which will **break the link** to the pattern swatch itself.

Comment: ok, I will investigate the issue. One thing is clear - the pattern-based filling cannot be directly editable.